# Is there a good way to inspect objects whose type is derived from the EntityDrupalWrapper class?

Tags: entities, debugging

I'm sure this question applies to other complex object types, but `EntityDrupalWrapper` is the one I'm currently working with. This is the type of object returned by [`entity_metadata_wrapper()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21entity%21entity.module/function/entity_metadata_wrapper/7) (and probably others).

When using code like the following:

```
$order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order_object);
dpm($order_wrapper);
```

the output from Devel is none too helpful:

[image: screenshot]

It doesn't show what you'd expect to see for a call to `dpm()` with, for example, a `stdClass` object.

A similar call to `dvm()` does print the object, but in a manner I'm not familiar with, and it's not very readable.

I've tried `debug()` and it produces a PHP user notice that looks something like this:

[image: screenshot 2]

Incidentally the HTML output contained in that warning is the same output that `dvm()` prints to the screen.

How can I inspect these types of objects (preferably with Krumo), so I can see what properties are available? Or am I stuck using `dvm()`?

Comment: try debug() introduced in Drupal 7

Comment: Thanks @ShuaibNawaz, even less success with that one though I'm afraid (I've updated the question)

Comment: Yep, that's exactly one of the problems with the wrapper classes. dpm()/krumo only sees public properties. Everything in the wrapper classes is protected and access through magic __get() and __set() methods.

Comment: @Berdir I was afraid of that; I hadn't looked but it did smell a lot like `__get()` and `__set()` were involved. Out of interest do you have any preferred way of finding out what class properties are available for what wrapper? Or is it just a matter of 'knowing' based on experience?

Comment: @Berdir I don't think you'll get notified of this, you can use `dpm($wrapper->getPropertyInfo());`, it really helps things

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use dpm($wrapper->getPropertyInfo());

It's in [the docs](http://drupal.org/node/1021556).

Comment: And to inspect particular fields from your node you can use `kpr($wrapper->my_custom_field->value());`

Answer (score 4):

I had been playing with EntityDrupalWrapper objects.
debug() usually returns the output that may have prepared by __toString()

I iterated EntityDrupalWrapper object using foreach and it helped to list down the name of properties.

```
foreach($order_wrapper as $name => $obj){
  debug($name);
  debug(get_class($obj)); //EntityValueWrapper
}
```

Here `$obj` is an object of type [`EntityValueWrapper`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!includes!entity.wrapper.inc/class/EntityValueWrapper/7)

$obj can be read by $obj->value() and can be write by $obj->set('value');

EDIT:

If you have created your wrapper without passing second param
i.e. entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order');
then set and value methods will throw exception as they are not implemented.

Answer (score 4):

I wound up writing my own little widget to unroll the wrapper:

```
function _wrapper_debug($w) {
  $values = array();
  foreach ($w->getPropertyInfo() as $key => $val) {
    $values[$key] = $w->$key->value();
  }
  return $values;
}

dpm(_wrapper_debug($some_object_wrapper));
```

Hope someone finds it useful.

Answer (score 3):

The [Inspect](http://drupal.org/project/inspect) module provides a nice structural view of the data you want to debug.

> Get instructive and well formatted variable dumps, deep stack traces, and execution time profiles - to database log (Reports / Recent log messages), to file or to screen.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to inspect the original object that is "powering" the wrapper, try:

```
dpm($wrapper->raw())
```

This works well for me.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [devel patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/krumo_with_protected_private_and_PUBLIC.patch) the enables Krumo to show all private and protected properties.

[Here is the thread on drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/927690)

I've found this patch very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use the drupal cli

```
$ drupal debug:entity
// Displays current events
```