# Debug EntityFieldQuery?

Tags: 7, entities, debugging

I have a module which is misbehaving. An EFQ is returing unexpected results, but I can't see *why* just by looking at the code. Is there a [dpq()](http://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpq/) equivalent for EFQs? Other ways of debugging them?

Comment: Similar question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33473/is-there-a-good-way-to-inspect-objects-whose-type-is-derived-from-the-entitydrup. Can you cast the query object to a string to inspect it to see if the SQL gives any clues?

Comment: Great suggestions, however: Recoverable fatal error: Object of class EntityFieldQuery could not be converted to string :(

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's a wee bit of a hack, but you could add a tag to any `EntityFieldQuery` you're interested in printing the query for, then implement [`hook_query_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_query_alter/7) to intercept it when it's a standard `SelectQuery`, then cast it to string for debugging:

```
function MYMODULE_query_alter($query) {
  if ($query->hasTag('efq_debug')) {
    dpm((string)$query);
  }
}

$q = new EntityFieldQuery;
$q->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->addTag('efq_debug')
  ->execute();
```

It's a bit of a hack but does the trick. The output for the above is:

```
SELECT node.nid AS entity_id, node.vid AS revision_id, node.type AS bundle, :entity_type     
AS entity_type
FROM {node} node
```

Presumably this will also only work when using MySQL as the field storage system.

Comment: Sounds great in theory, but what about the comments on the question? EFQ doesn't implement __toString()?

Comment: By the time it gets to `hook_query_alter()` the query isn't an `EntityFieldQuery` any more, it's been converted down to a standard `db_select()`, so `__tostring()` works great :) Since working this out I've been using it quite a lot and it works pretty well

Comment: Confirmed that casting to string works once the query gets to `hook_query_alter()`.

Comment: To see the query argumentos (":entity_type" in the above example) you can use dpm($query->arguments());

Answer (score 15):

Rather than rolling your own hook_query_alter() you can let [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module do the heavy lifting for you by adding the `debug` tag:

```
$q = new EntityFieldQuery;
$q->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node');
  ->addTag('debug')
  ->execute();
```

This will print the query to screen, just like `dpq()` would.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the @Clive answer, which generally prints the query with the placeholder not along with the value. To print the value with the query use the following code under the hook_query_alter.

```
function hook_query_alter($query) {
  if ($query->hasTag('debug')) {
    $sql = (string)$query;
    $connection = Database::getConnection();
    foreach ((array) $query->arguments() as $key => $val) {
      $quoted[$key] = $connection->quote($val);
    }
    $sql = strtr($sql, $quoted);
    dpm($sql);
  }
}


$q = new EntityFieldQuery;
$q->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node');
  ->addTag('debug');
  ->execute();
```

It is not good practice to install a module for the few lines of code. That is why I opted for the aforementioned solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you download the dev version of [Nice DPQ](https://www.drupal.org/project/nicedpq) (or anything => 1.1), you can simply do:

```
$user_query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$user_query->entityCondition('entity_type','user');
$user_query->addTag('nicedpq');
$user_result = $user_query->execute();
```

and you will get the query dpm'ed nicely :). The important part in the code above is **addTag('nicedpq')** - that triggers the `dpm()`.

Comment: nice alternate workaround to devel. Couldn't find that module directly over DO because they removed related module block which was there earliar.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to debug it via [XDebug](http://xdebug.org). Once installed, do `xdebug_start_trace()` before the code, and `xdebug_stop_trace()` after that, then you'll have clear trace log what was executed and where.

Also you can enable query logger in MySQL configuration.

The other method is to use strace/truss/dtruss like debuggers.

Example using dtruss:

- all queries

  ```
  sudo dtruss -t read -n mysqld
  ```
- specific queries

  ```
  sudo dtruss -t read -n mysqld 2>&1 | grep SPECIFIC_TEXT
  ```

Note that `dtruss` is just a script which uses DTrace, so you may consider a direct implementation of [PHP DTrace static probes](http://php.net/manual/en/features.dtrace.dtrace.php) or [DTracing MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/getting_started_dtrace_saha.html) by writing your own script.

Read more: [Advanced debugging of Drupal core using the command line (strace & tcpdump)](https://drupal.org/node/1817744)

Answer (score 0):

Add this function to your module.  Then, add the tag `debug` to any EFQ.  Requires Devel module to be enabled in order to print the query.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_query_TAG_alter().
 *
 * Add the tag 'debug' to any EFQ and this will print the query to the messages.
 *
 * @param \QueryAlterableInterface $query
 */
function MYMODULE_query_debug_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {
  if (function_exists('dpq') && !$query->hasTag('debug-semaphore')) {
    $query->addTag('debug-semaphore');
    dpq($query);
  }
}
```