# EntityFieldQuery with fieldCondition returns nothing

Tags: entities

I have created a custom entity, called 'point'.

I'm able to get all of the entities in the db, with this:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'point')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', 'point');
$result = $query->execute();
```

But when I add a fieldCondition, to make sure I only get the one single entity I want, I'll get an empty array back.

It looks like this:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'point')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', 'point')
    ->fieldCondition('field_point_unique_number', 'value', $unique_number, '=');
$result = $query->execute();
```

Where $unique_number is a textstring. And it's not a typo in the textstring.
In the db the field 'field_point_unique_number' is a varchar, but only contains numbers.

Why does the fieldCondition return nothing?

Comment: What drupal type of field is "field_point_unique_number"? Check database table field_data_field_point_unique_number, what columns does this table contain?

Comment: The drupal type of the field 'field_point_unique_number' is 'text'.
In the database, the column I'm trying to make the condition on is 'field_point_unique_number' and its type is varchar.

Comment: The code is correct for the configuration you described, check the data in `$unique_number` is what you expect, and the same for the data in the database (make sure there are no leading/trailing spaces, etc) See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36542/debug-entityfieldquery for suggestions on seeing the generated query string so you can check for anomalies there too

Comment: In the database the table should be named "field_data_field_point_unique_number" and there should be a column named "field_point_unique_number_value". You said the column is named "field_point_unique_number". Please be exact about the terms like "table" and "column" and check this.

Comment: You are right about that Stefan. The column is called "field_point_unique_number_value". I wrote that wrong.

I'll try to check that Clive

Comment: I was sure that I had checked the input already, but I hadn't checked it for trailing spaces. So using trim() on $unique_number did the trick.
Thanks for leading me the right way Clive!

Answer (score -1):

I hadn't checked it for trailing spaces. So using trim() on $unique_number did the trick. Thanks for leading me the right way Clive!