# Output of entity_metadata_wrapper does not dump to dsm()/dpm()

Tags: entities

Given this code in a theme_preprocess_page($vars)..

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
dsm($wrapper);
```

Why doesn't $wrapper produce a debug dump in dsm() or dsp()? I can get data using print_r. Can someone please explain this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Never mind, I found it. Leaving the answer here for anyone who follows

Basically, `dpm($wrapper->getPropertyInfo());`

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/42542